# Emulator internet works in browser not in app

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my Android emulator the internet works in the browser but I can't connect to my server through my app.  My app uses google maps v2 for Android.  I am using the regular android emulator and not the google api emulator because the map strangely doesn't show up on the google api emulator.  I think that may be why I'm getting this message though:
Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices

I also have the correct key as the app works fine on my device.  This is a very confusing issue and thank you for any help and I will do my best to give any more info needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maps v2 is not supported on any emulator image.  It requires Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks but actually everything works fine as long as I use localhost and not my server.  Seems a little weird to me.  If you know why that might be I would be very appreciative.  And if you know how I can connect my app to my server that would be awesome.

Comment: Ok I didn't realize this was pirating software.  I guess I'll be a good boy and just test it on my device.  Thanks.